# Display an error message popup when file path on JFileChooser is invalid

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I'd like to display an error message popup on top of a JFileChooser when user types in an invalid path.

I can make the popup show up by using JOptionPane, but not sure how to make it on top of the JFileChooser.  I'd also like the program returns to the file chooser when user clicks 'OK' on the popup. How do I do these?

Edit: Is it possible to validate the path when user is typing?

Comment: How can you define invalid path by using `JFileChooser`. I don't remember if you can

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin User can type in an invalid path. Then in the program, validates chooser.getSelectedFile(). Not sure if this is what you are asking?

Comment: JFileChooser will not know if the file is valid or not, you have to make some changes to it to do so, maybe try to inherit and override the selection? Otherwise you have to validate after and then reopen the file chooser

Comment: @porfiriopartida Yes, I've tried to reopen the file chooser but it looks funny. Users aren't happy about it.

Comment: Maybe you need your own file chooser. It is possible to validate or add more things if you have access to the jTextField in the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to override `approveSelection` if you want to show error message when File Chooser is opened:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(){

        @Override
        public void approveSelection(){
            File f = getSelectedFile();
            if(!f.exists() ){                   
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");                   
            }
        }           
    };

    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Open test");
    fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getFileFilter());  //remove the default file filter
    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML file", "xml");

    fc.addChoosableFileFilter(filter); //add XML file filter

    //show dialog
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(appFrame); 

    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){/* ...  */}
```

[image]

Hope it will help you

Comment: Yes. But what I want is an error message box to show up if user type in an invalid path to that xml.

Comment: changed, seems what you are looking for,

Comment: I agree, I think this would solve the Question. The validation you are asking now is out of the scope of the first question.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. Yes this is what I want. I tried it before and didn't work somehow and it turned out that our chooser infrastructure needs to be improved. Anyways, thanks for your answer. I've accepted it.